# Insert Bootstrap WYSIWYG content with ajax inside modal

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I'm using bootstrap3-wysiwyg. Code below works onload of page. This doesn't work when put inside an event, especially not inside $.ajax.

```
$('.textarea').html('Some text dynamically set.');
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        $('.textarea').html(data);
    }
});
```

`data` displays fine inside the textarea if without the wysiwyg, so I'm sure that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it.

"The key is to make sure that the editor is set up on the show event of the modal not on document ready." ~ ndogaru

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        $('.textarea').html(data);
        $('.textarea').wysihtml5();
    }
});
```

https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/issues/268

I hope this helps!